# How do I find all the non CLS-compliant statements in my .NET code?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, cls-compliant

How do I find all the non CLS-compliant statements in my .NET code?

Can Visual Studio 2015 compiler do it? How do I find non CLS-compliant warnings?

I've checked [StyleCop ReSharper extension](https://resharper-plugins.jetbrains.com/packages/StyleCop.StyleCop) and [ndepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) without success.

What I am after is to find all the non CLS-compliant statements in my C# code Visual Studio project. The final goal is to add the `[assembly: CLSCompliant(true)]` tag to it.

Thanks.

Comment: Using `[assembly: CLSCompliant(true)]` would make the c# compiler to show warnings on not CLS-compliant code. So what else do you need?

Comment: I've many warnings and don't know how to identify the CLS-compliant ones.

Comment: Well, they are (i think all of them) in the `CS3000` range

Comment: I didn't have the Code column visible in my Error List window. Now I can see them and sort by Code, many `CS3000` warning appeared. Thanks so much, please add and answer so I can mark the post answered.

Comment: Glad it helped Alberto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `[assembly: CLSCompliant(true)]` would make the c# compiler to show warnings on not CLS-compliant code. The code for CLSCompliant warnings is usually in the `CS3000` range, so you can order by code to check all of them.

Answer (score 0):

For VB.NET use this:

```
<Assembly: CLSCompliant(True)>
```

Also, don't forget to Build-Clean Solution and Build-Rebuild Solution after adding the above to the AssemblyInfo.vb file.

Comment: I'd like to think that a VB.NET developer, particularly one cognizant of CLS compliance issues, would know how to perform the minimal transformation from the accepted C# answer to their own language.

Comment: @BACON - Why not make it easy?

Comment: I've seen the "Why not make it easy?" argument made on these C#-to-VB.NET translation answers before, or even answers that just take another answer and repackage it as an extension method. The point is that this is derivative of and barely different than another answer, which I don't think justifies bumping a nearly three-year-old question to the top of the front page. If the code was wildly different between the two languages you'd certainly have a case, but here the only difference is the type of brackets used; I know VB.NET will accept a lowercase `true` and maybe even the `assembly:`, too.